# Inject hotjar script into angular page inside head element

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to add conditions to load this script in the head tag. I need to check if the URL is from our live domain then only it runs otherwise not. I could simply add this script to the head if there was no condition requirement. How I can inject this script in the head tag in angular?

For eg:

`window.origin == 'https://www.stackoverflow.com'` then inject this script into the head tag otherwise not.

```
<script>
        (function(h,o,t,j,a,r){
            h.hj=h.hj||function(){(h.hj.q=h.hj.q||[]).push(arguments)};
            h._hjSettings={hjid:*******,hjsv:*};
            a=o.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            r=o.createElement('script');r.async=1;
            r.src=t+h._hjSettings.hjid+j+h._hjSettings.hjsv;
            a.appendChild(r);
        })(window,document,'https://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-','.js?sv=');
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle this in one of your components, preferably in app.component. You could check the URL of course but more elegant would be to have some flag like `enableHotjarTracking` in your `environment.ts` file and set it to true only for your production environment.

Then you could call it as follows in your `app.component.ts`

```js
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

...

// inject document wrapper
constructor(
 @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,
){}

ngAfterContentInit() {
  if(environment.enableHotjarTracking) {
          ((h, o, t, j, a, r) => {
            h.hj =
              h.hj ||
              /* tslint:disable:only-arrow-functions */
              function () {
                (h.hj.q = h.hj.q || []).push(arguments);
              };
            h._hjSettings = { hjid: xxxx, hjsv: x };
            a = o.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            r = o.createElement('script');
            r.async = 1;
            r.src = t + h._hjSettings.hjid + j + h._hjSettings.hjsv;
            a.appendChild(r);
          })(window as any, this.document, 'https://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-', '.js?sv=');
  }
}
```

You could also keep your hotjar id in the environment file.

Comment: I was using ngx-hotjar but this no longer works with Angular 16 so I tried this method and it seems to work well.